# React can't get response body from PHP API

Tags: php, reactjs, api

I'm trying to send a POST request to my PHP file and get a response. The response is sent with code 200, however, I don't see what PHP returns. Here is my react code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'Hello!' })
    }

    fetch('http://localhost:80/react/db.php',requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      alert('error')
    })
  },[])
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo "data";
```

Logging `response` on console returns me:
[image]
I can't get the "data" out of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 fetch('http://localhost:80/react/db.php',requestOptions)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
}).catch(err => {
  alert('error')
})
```

Comment: It shows 'undefined'. I added json_encode on the PHP file, still the same.

Comment: it returns Promise<pending>

Comment: the answer above should now display the data

Comment: It worked. Thank you, is this same as ```data=await response.json()```?